# Make all JS wait for page load

Tags: javascript, html

I have alot of javascript on a page, It can't be combined.

It's bugging me with the amount of "document.wait" and so forth functions on each of them, is there a better way of doing this, or am I stuck with it?

Goog'ling has revealed nothing.

Comment: You might want to google again, this time with `load event`.

Comment: you should use:
$(function(){
//type code here//
}); 
its not just waiting for the page load, but also prevent users to run your functions on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by others move all your scripts to the bottom of the page, right before `</body>`. It will solve many of your issues. But it will not tackle all the subtleties of browser-inconsistencies specially for old IE.

If you want to get a glimpse of how tricky is to provide such cross-browser implementation, take a look at the following popular question:

[$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

For instance do not lean against `document.addEventListener` as IE proposes its own proprietary `document.attachEvent`. And this is only the very first step.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to always put script tags just before you close the body:

```
  <script src="path/to/my/script"></script>
  <!-- more scripts, etc -->
</body>
```

This way, everything else is definitely already loaded and no need to "wait".
**[See this recommendation from google.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_javascript_last)**

Otherwise, you can use:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  //your js here
});
```